# error #1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql

when i try to update the data in a csv file into mysql database im getting these following errors,can u guys help me out

```
UPDATE into 'td_demo'('Vehicle_description','Status','Conditions', 'Wholesale','Pickup_Location','Year','VIN','Make','Body_Style','Model','Doors','Trim_Level','Vehicle_Type','Odometer','Salvage','As_Is','Fuel_Type','Title_State','Engine','Title_Status','Displacement','Drive_Train', 'Transmission','Interior_Type','Exterior_Color','Top_Type','Interior_Color','Stereo','Window_Sticker','Airbags','Equipments','Image_directory') values('2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','')
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'into 'td_excel'('Vehicle_description','Status','Conditions', 'Wholesale','Pickup' at line 1**

Comment: get rid off all single quotes in table and column names.

Comment: `UPDATE into ...` is not valid sql. Please take a look at the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: @abhik chakraborty : will it upload if i didnt use the column name?

Comment: No it won't. You have to solve the issue reported in the error message. Programming is not a guessing game. You have to obey strict rules. And a good way to start is reading and understanding the error messages you get. The one you got is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of Issues:

- You are using update into which is not valid. You may consult [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for syntax. While i think you are looking for insertion of a row, So it should be:

  INSERT INTO td_demo (field1, field2) values (1, 2)

You could consult syntax for insertion [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)

- You have asked 31 fields for population while passing 33 field values.
- You could make it more better readable by removing Quotes in column names.

Comment: There is some data which is already there in table..so now i want to add more data to the table using csv file...what should i use insert or update

Comment: then you should be updating the row. So update td_demo set field1='2', field2='2'

Comment: ok fine but i cant directly give values to field..i will post the exact code used to update using csv file

Comment: Please post it in another question as this will be out of scope of your current question where you were using wrong syntax and you wanted to know the reason for the same. So close this one and open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

@almas shaikh

//Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$import="UPDATE into `td_excel`(`Vehicle_description`,`Status`,`Conditions`, `Wholesale`,`Pickup_Location`,`Year`,`VIN`,`Make`,`Body_Style`,`Model`,`Doors`,`Trim_Level`, `Vehicle_Type`,`Odometer`,`Salvage`,`As_Is`,`Fuel_Type`,`Title_State`,`Engine`,`Title_Status`,`Displacement`,`Drive_Train`,`Transmission`,    `Interior_Type`,`Exterior_Color`,`Top_Type`,`Interior_Color`,`Stereo`,`Window_Sticker`,`Airbags`,   `Equipments`,`Image_directory`) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13]','$data[14]','$data[15]','$data[16]','$data[17]','$data[18]','$data[19]','$data[20]','$data[21]','$data[22]','$data[23]','$data[24]','$data[25]','$data[26]','$data[27]','$data[28]','$data[29]','$data[30]','$data[31]','$data[32]')"

```
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);
```